# Web Based Windows Explorer for Linux System

Tags: linux, file-management, gui, webgui

Does anyone know of a program/script that runs on Linux that can give us a nice GUI for browsing and managing shared system folders similar in the way that windows explorer would work?

So would allow, upload, download, file modification etc.  It's a way to still have access to all our files stored on the system from any location with internet access.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/index.php?opc=4&lg=ing) is nice, of course you will need Apache and PHP installed.

**upload:**

[image]

**download:**

[image]

**file modification:**

[image]

and [much more](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/index.php?opc=4&lg=ing).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try FileThingie (http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) or PHP File Manager (phpfm.sourceforge.net). FileThingie's UI is much nicer than PHP File Manager's, but personally I think PHP File Navigator's UI is even better. Matter of opinion really, though.